# Summer Internships (for IT/Security/Networking?)

Tags: network

I know these are a common thing to do during the Summer semester for Computer Science students at large companies like Facebook, Apple, Google, etc.

Are there similar internships available for IT students? Security? Hell, even Business? I'm majoring in Management Information Science (Bachelors, falls under Business Administration) and will soon have two Associates (Information Systems Security and Network Design).

From what I could tell in my short search, the most "security sounding" one @ FB still wanted you to be a amazing programmer, something which I am not.

I applied for this: https://www.facebook.com/careers/department.php?dept=interns&req=a2KA0000000La9gMAC Probably a bit of a stretch, but whatever, can't hurt!

Found this, seems like a good candidate for AFTER graduation w/ Bachelors: https://www.facebook.com/careers/department.php?dept=grads&req=a2KA0000000LbVuMAK

Answer (score 3):

You may have luck selling the idea to a small company with no ITSEC department. I would sell the idea as a IT Security best practice analysis. Suggestions would be to analyze their public website for issues found in the OWASP top 10. Evaluate how their server and workstation management/policies/procedures stack up against the SANS TOP 20. Evaluate the effectiveness of their IDP/IDS if they have it; Install and configure SNORT if they don't. It would be a win-win situation.

Comment: That could be a good idea, although I imagine it would be hard to "sell myself" to a small company in that sense?